# Android Market Filter Help Needed

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to upload my first android application to android market. But when I upload it it showed that it has 2 market filter

android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen

I don't have any filter in manifest file. Whats wrong here? plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my upload say that, thats like standard. You have to use the "android.hardware.telephony" because that's indicating that your using a Telephone Device (NOT A TABLET) and "android.hardware.touchscreen" because the device is activated by touch.